# How to markup GUI menu commands

Tags: environments, best-practices, semantics

I am writing user documentation for custom software, and am wondering if there is a built-in command, library, or "best practice" for marking up GUI commands semantically? The idea is something along the lines of:

```latex
\item {
    The user should select the \texttt{File \textrightarrow Save} option...
}
```

Is there anything of that sort that exists, or should I just use either `texttt` or `textbf`?

Comment: Package [`menukeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) may help.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ that's perfect, thank you. Convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The menukeys package imho still uses the catoptions package which is not compatible with everything. Use it with care and search the site for possible problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is there an alternative?